# Disable Audition playhead "Follow Song"

Tags: playback, looping, adobe-audition

In Adobe Audition, how to have an audio track playing, zoomed somewhere, and have the "portion of the audio track that is zoomed in" to not follow the playhead? In case I want to fine-tune the marker position for a loop, for example (by the way, is there a simpler way to do that?). In Propellerhead Reason there's a "Follow Song" option that enables/disables it. 
 I can't find anything in Google so probably I'm not using the correct terminology used for that in Audition.

**UPDATE**

I just learned that *Shift + X* [Makes Playhead Return To Original Position in Adobe Audition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E86T8iRgA5U), which solves the problem (for my specific case, at least).

Comment: please post your Update as an answer and mark it as the correct answer, so we can close the question. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Audition version 12 (CC 2019)

To prevent auto-scroll from being turned on, uncheck:

Edit ► Preferences ► Playback ► **Enable auto-scroll when starting playback or recording**

[image: auto-scroll setting]

To disable auto-scroll when it is on, press **A** or press the auto-scroll button at the top-right of the timeline

[image: auto-scroll button]

## Audition version 5 (CS 6) and above

Edit ► Preferences ► Playback ► Uncheck "Auto-scroll during playing and recording" box.